# Custom UITabBarController -- Best Approach

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

What would be the best way to create a completely custom `UITabBarController` look alike.

I need full customization of its size, animate it, etc.

A solution that I have is just using a `UIView` for the tabbarcontroller that then replaces the `UIView` above it depending on what button is selected on that `UIView`.

What is the best approach?

Comment: you might get further here if you pick one aspect of behavior at a time - something you want to improve in your class, then post the code about that in a question about that.  lot's of folks will jump in to help you.  otherwise, they might see this question and just shrug.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty good guide for doing just that:
http://www.felipecypriano.com/2012/02/27/how-to-customize-uitabbar-on-ios-5/

This example is taken from that site:

Basically create a backgroundImage, selectionIndicatorImage, adjust the fonts as appropriate.

```
// Probably put these in your AppDelegate, setup the background and selection image
[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected"]];

// In your VC which is inside the tab bar
- (id)init {
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyNibName" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"The Title" image:nil tag:0];
        [[self tabBarItem] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_icon"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_icon"]];
        [[self tabBarItem] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```